# jQuery rules validation with ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, validationrules

This question already asked but that not working.

I want to use `jQuery` rules validation with show `Zone Name Already Exist...!` message using `Ajax`. I tried `submitHandler` but that not working.

This is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
    $("#zoneForm").validate({
        rules: {
            'zoneName': {
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 15
            }
        },
        validClass: "success",
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        },
        submitHandler: function(e) {
            var zoneVal = $('#zoneName').val();
            console.log(zoneVal);
            e.preventDefault();
            if (zoneVal) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>zone/zoneCheck',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        zoneName: zoneVal
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        alert(data);
                        if (data == 1) {
                            alert('Zone Name Already Exist.');
                        } else if (data == 0) {
                            $("#zoneForm").submit();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src=""></script>
<form id="zoneForm" name="zoneForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('zone/editzone');?>">
 <label>Zone Name <span class="required-label">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control zoneEditName" id="zoneEditName" name="zoneName" placeholder="Enter Zone Name" required />
  <input class="btn btn-success zoneSubmit" type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Change type="submit" to type="button" in to from submit button.

Comment: @KoratPrakash: why i want to change type='button' ?

Comment: because you have submit form from ajax. $("#zoneForm").submit();

Answer (score 0):

Use remote function in your jquery it might helps you to check isExists

see below example

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "check-email.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          username: function() {
            return $( "#username" ).val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

or you can refer https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: I tried validation not working properly i got `Please fix this field.` error message

Comment: i think you have problem in your response so check your request it works proper or not.

Comment: and you can customize error msg to whatever you want so that msg will appear instead of 'please fix this field'.

Comment: Am sending zoneName value to my controller and model. That sending response 1 or 0. So if i got 1 means data already exits and if response 0 means no data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181525/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-rahul-dudharejiya).

Comment: yes exactly the response is same as you said so if your response every time comes with 1 then there is problem with your controller try to check over their

Comment: No i got both 0 and 1